# Reinstall wayland - 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, wayland

I recently had some nvidia troubles (big surprise) and needed to purge my nvidia drivers and reinstall them. When I rebooted, I noticed I lost wayland as an option at the login menu.

This is my work machine and I rather not thrash around in experimental territory, does anyone know the exact apt packages I need to reinstall to get this option back and sure up my install with what was once stock?

Comment: I wasn't aware that Wayland even works with the Nvidia drivers at all? Last I heard Nvidia implemented something differently than the Linux community wanted and so development was at a standstill.

Answer (score 1):

[android-dev](https://askubuntu.com/users/518562/android-dev) is correct, when you enable the nvidia drivers the wayland option does indeed vanish from the list of available desktop environments at login. I switched back to the nouveau drivers and wayland came back as an option. Toggled to nvidia-390 and it went away again.